# Proof of friends relationship for a Canadian visitor visa

Tags: canada, standard-visitor-visas

I’m applying for a visitor visa to see a friend.  I have my letter of invitation.  But at the questioner ask me about proof of relationship what can I submit?

---

After you reply you will be visiting any friends and you said you have an invitation letter at the final ask you to upload any proof of relation with the person such as marriage certificate , or common law or birth certificate but that doesnt apply for me because i wanna visit a friend not a family member. if i apply for a toursim visa then dont ask you but cant add the invitation either .

Comment: What makes you think they would ask for proof of relationship when you're not related?

Comment: Is this a romantic relationship? Have you met in person before? If so, pictures of you two together, any trips you've taken together, records of online chats...